# Batch edit (not rename) file properties in windows

Tags: windows, file-management

I have a large directory of downloaded shareware. I keep track of what i have
by individually editing the properties of each program. However, some of the
programs are multipart .rar types. And i have at least a few hundred programs
so far.

I am looking for a utility that will let me batch edit file properties such as
Title, Author, Summary, and Comments, so I don't have to edit each file or
file part individually. Windows doesn't let me do this in Explorer. Powerdesk
has a proprietary system, but it isn't preserved when moving or copying files.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk), it can edit properties and attributes. It's freeware.

Comment: How do you edit properties using Bulk Rename Utility?  I can only figure out how to rename files.

Answer (score -2):

This capability is built into Windows 11 (and possibly earlier versions). I am unsure if this was the case when the question was asked. Here are the steps:

1. Select the files you want to edit metadata for
2. Right click and select "Properties"
3. Click the "Details" tab
4. Edit the value(s) you wish to change
5. Click "OK"

If like me you were looking to remove property values, after Step 3, performing the following:

4. Click the blue link "Remove Properties and Personal Information"
5. Select the "Remove the following properties from this file" radio button
6. Enable the checkboxes next to the properties you wish to remove
7. Click "OK"