# About adding Windows file properties from CLI (esp. for .mkv files)

Tags: windows, command-line, video, batch, matroska

**[Context]** I have a large collection of movies that have been grouped by their Genre. But now, I have all the files from all years of release in the same folder (I don't want to sub-divide by folders now, or prefix movie name with year, as I would want to sort by Movie name also).

**[Requirement]** I would like to be able to sort (and search) these files by "Year" property in the Windows explorer.

**[Attempted solutions]** I have bulk extracted their metadata from their respective .nfo files. Now I would like to batch edit the file properties.
I have made several attemtps at (batch) editing metadata in Windows. Could not find a generic solution (esp. for .mkv files). The [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/67427/batch-edit-not-rename-file-properties-in-windows) post does not work.

I came across [Atomicparsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) (for Windows). This does suit my use case, but for .mp4 files only. The below statement adds "Year" and "Genre" properties to files from "cmd".

```
C:\path\to\AtomicParsley.exe "D:\path\to\myMovie).mp4" --overWrite --year 2016 --genre "Thriller, Science Fiction, Drama"
```

I was able to bulk create these and batch edit all my mp4 files using the extracted metadata I already had.

However, Atomicparsley seems to incapable of editing the properties of .mkv or .avi files. I tried the following other methods also, to no success:

- [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/). I could not add Genre or Year. But added properties like "Title", which did not get reflected in File Properties in the Windows explorer.
- [mkvpropedit](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html) in Mac OS (I made my NTFS hard drive writable in Mac using ntfs-3g). However, I could not find a way to add/edit genre or year property (I don't even know if it would get reflected back in the Windows OS).
- I gave up on batch update and tried to manually update a .mkv file. The properties behave like an immutable set in the Windows File Details, and I could not add a Year or Genre, nor could I edit any existing fields.

**[Question]** Can someone suggest ways to achieve the following (in increasing order of preference):

1. Add File properties (preferably, Genre & Year) to a .mkv file in Windows (via CLI or GUI) that are visible in the File Explorer (If these properties are not available to .mkv files, I just need any other properties which I can use to store these).
2. Batch Add File properties (preferably, Genre & Year) to a .mkv file in Windows (via CLI or some tool like Bulk Rename Utility).
3. Batch Add File properties to any file in Windows.

Comment: Try to rename .mkv to .mp4, Then apply that tool to change metadata.